# How to add a UISwitch to a cell in a grouped table view?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

So I'm creating a settings page in my app and up to now I've set it up with a grouped table view with both group titles and settings/cell tiles.

At this point I'd like to add UISwitches (Already have their properties set up) to each cell. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a `UISwitch` as the accessory view for the `UITableViewCell`.

```
UISwitch* aswitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
aswitch.on = YES; // or NO
cell.accessoryView = aswitch;
[aswitch release];
```